# R/SQL: Finding Out If Table Contains A Certain Value

Tags: sql, r, netezza

I am working **Netezza** SQL.

Suppose I have 3 tables located on a server (e.g. in real life there could be many such tables and each table with many rows and many columns):

- table1: col1,col2,col3
- table2: col4,col5,col6
- table3: col7,col8, col9
- etc.

**My Question:** I am trying to find out which columns from which tables contain values %LIKE% "ABC" (i.e. if the column has a row that contains a value %LIKE% "ABC")

I thought that maybe using R/SQL together might be a better way to solve this problem because I don't think there is a way to do this exclusively using Netezza SQL (perhaps this is possible with a dynamic query, but this looks very difficult.

**Step 1:** I have this information in a table already (created using the built-in `information_schema.column` table within Netezza):

```
# I re-created this for the stackoverflow example

table_name = c("table1","table1", "table1", "table2","table2", "table2", "table3", "table3", "table3")
col_name = c("col1","col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6","col7", "col8", "col9")

summary = data.frame(table_name, col_name)

  table_name col_name
1     table1     col1
2     table1     col2
3     table1     col3
4     table2     col4
5     table2     col5
6     table2     col6
7     table3     col7
8     table3     col8
9     table3     col9
```

**Step 2:** I created a column of SQL queries that I will be sending:

```
# generate a column of SQL queries to be sent
summary$queries = SQL(paste0("select * from ", summary$table_name, " where ", "summary$col_name " ," LIKE %abc%"))

table_name col_name                                                 queries
1     table1     col1 select * from table1 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
2     table1     col2 select * from table1 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
3     table1     col3 select * from table1 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
4     table2     col4 select * from table2 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
5     table2     col5 select * from table2 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
6     table2     col6 select * from table2 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
7     table3     col7 select * from table3 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
8     table3     col8 select * from table3 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
9     table3     col9 select * from table3 where summary$col_name  LIKE %abc%
```

**Step 3:** Next, I wrote the following R code:

```
#import libraries
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

# connect
my_con <- dbConnect(odbc:: odbc()...)

# create for loop

my_list = list()

for (i in 1:nrow(summary)) {
  tryCatch({
    is_null_i = dbExecute(my_con, summary$queries[i])
    ifelse(is.null(is_null_i) == "FALSE", my_list[[i]] = is_null_i, NA)
  }, error = function(e) {
    # ignore error
  })
}
```

**My Problem:** Although each individual `dbExecute(my_con, summary$queries[i])` seems to run, is_null_i doe not see to be created.

In the end, I am looking for an output like this:

```
# hypothetical output tables and columns that contain the word %ABC%:

  table_name col_name
1     table1     col1
2     table1     col3
3     table3     col7
4     table3     col8
```

**Can someone please show me a better way to do this?** Perhaps it might be possible to do this exclusively in Netezza?

Thanks!

Comment: `"summary$col_name "` should not be quoted

Comment: You're abusing `ifelse` inside your `for` loop, and are bypassing some good features of the traditional `if` including short-circuiting. Also, comparing a logical with a string seems unnecessarily complicationg, is there a reason you don't use `!is.null(is_null_i)`?

Comment: You're using `dbExecute` which will not return data. Is there a reason you aren't using `dbGetQuery`? Also, `dbExecute` should be returning a scalar numeric; besides the typos in your queries, is there a reason it would return `NULL`?

Comment: @ r2evans: thank you so much for your replies! In general, do you think there is an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not really, I don't know of anything that automates looking across multiple tables (different columns per table) where there is no "joining" construct.

Comment: @ r2evans: I am using dbExecute because dbGetQuery will not run the SQL code. Only dbExecute is working  https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/sqlinterpolate

Comment: a useful link to test the SQL: https://sqliteonline.com/

Comment: `dbExecute(con, "select 1 as a")` returns `0`, which means my `select` query results were not returned by the call to `dbExecute`. [`?dbExecute`](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/dbexecute) states that it *"Executes a statement and returns the number of rows affected"*, I don't know how you expect to get rows returned by it; `sqlInterpolate` has nothing to do with returning data, just how you form the query itself.

Comment: A bunch of `select 'table1', 'col1' from table1 where col1 like '%abc%' union ... union select 'table999', 'col999' from table999 where col999 like '%abc%'` should do it, not as efficiently though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
```

We can use duckdb to create a small in-memory test setup

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = ":memory:")
```

Let’s say we have the following three tables:

```r
table1 <- tibble(
  col1 = c("A", "B", "aBc"),
  col2 = c("A", "B", "abc"),
  col3 = c("A", "B", "ABC")
)

table2 <- tibble(
  col4 = c("A", "B", "aBc"),
  col5 = c("A", "B", "ABC"),
  col6 = c("A", "B", "abc"),
  col7 = c("A", "B", "ABC")
)

table3 <- tibble(
  col8 = c("A", "B", "ABC"),
  col9 = c("A", "B", "abc"),
)

copy_to(con, table1)
copy_to(con, table2)
copy_to(con, table3)
```

And the expected output is therefore

```
table      column
table1     col3
table2     col5
table2     col7
table3     col8
```

As you know, we can list all the tables on the database “server”

```r
DBI::dbListTables(con)
#> [1] "table1" "table2" "table3"
```

We could in theory use a for loop, but for these kind of operations, I prefer
to keep things in a dataframe and rely on the different dplyr tools. To start
we can move the list of table names to a tibble with `enframe` and setup the
connections to the different remote tables. It can be done like this:

```r
(remote_data <- DBI::dbListTables(con) |> 
  enframe(value = "table_name") |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(
    data = list(tbl(con, table_name))
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    name table_name data          
#>   <int> <chr>      <list>        
#> 1     1 table1     <tbl_dck_[,3]>
#> 2     2 table2     <tbl_dck_[,4]>
#> 3     3 table3     <tbl_dck_[,2]>
```

So now we have a column with a list of connections to the duckdb tables.
Instead of manually constructing the queries, we can rely on the `dbplyr`
package to do the translation for us. Let’s start with just one of the tables

```r
remote_data[["data"]][[1]] |> 
  summarise(
    across(everything(), \(column) any(str_detect(column, "ABC")))
  ) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything())
#> Warning: Missing values are always removed in SQL aggregation functions.
#> Use `na.rm = TRUE` to silence this warning
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> # Source:   SQL [3 x 2]
#> # Database: DuckDB 0.5.1 [unknown@Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2:R 4.2.2/:memory:]
#>   name  value
#>   <chr> <lgl>
#> 1 col1  FALSE
#> 2 col2  FALSE
#> 3 col3  TRUE
```

And now, we can repeat it for all the remote tables like this

```r
(results <- remote_data |> 
  reframe(
    table_name, 
    data |> 
      summarise(
        across(everything(), \(column) any(str_detect(column, "ABC")))
      ) |> 
      pivot_longer(
        everything(), 
        names_to = "column_name", 
        values_to = "contains_value"
      ) |> 
      collect()
  ) |> 
  ungroup()
)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   table_name column_name contains_value
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <lgl>         
#> 1 table1     col1        FALSE         
#> 2 table1     col2        FALSE         
#> 3 table1     col3        TRUE          
#> 4 table2     col4        FALSE         
#> 5 table2     col5        TRUE          
#> 6 table2     col6        FALSE         
#> 7 table2     col7        TRUE          
#> 8 table3     col8        TRUE          
#> 9 table3     col9        FALSE
```

and to get the expected output, we just need to filter and select

```r
results |> 
  filter(contains_value) |> 
  select(-contains_value)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   table_name column_name
#>   <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 table1     col3       
#> 2 table2     col5       
#> 3 table2     col7       
#> 4 table3     col8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ Peter H: thank you so much for your answer! I look forward to trying this!

Comment: Just a question - I know my way is very inefficient  ... but do you know how I could use the approach I suggested in my question for this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: I've posted another answer where the queries are constructed "manually" if that's what you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

## setup ###########
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = ":memory:")
table1 <- tibble(
  col1 = c("A", "B", "aBc"),
  col2 = c("A", "B", "abc"),
  col3 = c("A", "B", "ABC")
)

table2 <- tibble(
  col4 = c("A", "B", "aBc"),
  col5 = c("A", "B", "ABC"),
  col6 = c("A", "B", "abc"),
  col7 = c("A", "B", "ABC")
)

table3 <- tibble(
  col8 = c("A", "B", "ABC"),
  col9 = c("A", "B", "abc"),
)
copy_to(con, table1)
copy_to(con, table2)
copy_to(con, table3)
####################
```

If you don’t want to rely on the translation from dbplyr, another alternative
would be to construct the queries yourself. I would suggest using `glue_sql`
from the glue package. It’s generally a bad practice to construct queries
using `paste` since you can run into issues with SQL injection.

```r
(queries_df <- DBI::dbListTables(con) |> 
  enframe(value = "table_name") |> 
  group_by(table_name) |> 
  reframe(
    column_name = DBI::dbListFields(con, table_name),
  ) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(
    query = glue::glue_sql(
      "select * from {`table_name`} where {`column_name`} like '%ABC%'",
      .con = con
    ) |> as.character()
  )
 
)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   table_name column_name query                                       
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>                                       
#> 1 table1     col1        select * from table1 where col1 like '%ABC%'
#> 2 table1     col2        select * from table1 where col2 like '%ABC%'
#> 3 table1     col3        select * from table1 where col3 like '%ABC%'
#> 4 table2     col4        select * from table2 where col4 like '%ABC%'
#> 5 table2     col5        select * from table2 where col5 like '%ABC%'
#> 6 table2     col6        select * from table2 where col6 like '%ABC%'
#> 7 table2     col7        select * from table2 where col7 like '%ABC%'
#> 8 table3     col8        select * from table3 where col8 like '%ABC%'
#> 9 table3     col9        select * from table3 where col9 like '%ABC%'
```

And then you can send of the queries with `DBI::dbGetQuery`. Here you could
use a for loop, but it’s probably easier to use map now that we already have
data in a tabular format.

```r
(results_df <- queries_df |> 
  mutate(
    results = map(query, \(.x) DBI::dbGetQuery(con, .x))
  )
)
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   table_name column_name query                                        results
#>   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>                                        <list> 
#> 1 table1     col1        select * from table1 where col1 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 2 table1     col2        select * from table1 where col2 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 3 table1     col3        select * from table1 where col3 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 4 table2     col4        select * from table2 where col4 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 5 table2     col5        select * from table2 where col5 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 6 table2     col6        select * from table2 where col6 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 7 table2     col7        select * from table2 where col7 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 8 table3     col8        select * from table3 where col8 like '%ABC%' <df>   
#> 9 table3     col9        select * from table3 where col9 like '%ABC%' <df>
```

You could then get the expected results like this:

```r
results_df |> 
  filter(map_int(results, nrow) != 0) |> 
  select(table_name, column_name)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   table_name column_name
#>   <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 table1     col3       
#> 2 table2     col5       
#> 3 table2     col7       
#> 4 table3     col8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>